# How dynamically map Rest request

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

I have a Restful web service and I exposed a PATCH method for one of my resources.
Every request that the web service is getting is mapped to object:

```
class PatchRequest{

       private List<PatchElement> patchElements;

       ....getter and setter....
}


class PatchElement{

       private String path;   
       private Object value;  
       private String op; 

       ...getters and setters...
}
```

It works fine for "replace" PATCH operation and now I'm trying to extend the PATCH to support also "add" patch operation.
Meaning I need to support these kind of requests:

```
{
   patchElements" : [
       { "op": "add", "path": "/notes", "value": {"text":"some text"}}
      ]
 }
```

Where "notes" is `List<Note> notes` attribute on the resource I PATCH.

It means that for the above PATCH request I need to map the passed value to Note object, but as you can see the value is mapped to Object value in PatchElement.

How can I dynamically choose to which class to map the value in the REST request?

Thanks.